# Custom parsefilter.json file not found when running StormCrawler from Eclipse

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I wanted to report that, I have been investigating StormCrawler SDK for extracting HTML response. I know that JSoupParserBolt uses parsefilter.json file to extract the response according to a specific need. I also know that there is a default file for the same purpose. In my case, I am using Eclipse to execute the pom.xml file to generate .jar file for the crawler designed. Then I am running the CrawlTopology class containing the main function and a run function consisting all the required spout and bolt references from the SDK, forming a Topology(I used maven archtype to download the example crawler).
The problem is that the CrawlTopology class is not calling the modified parsefilter.json file to refer to the required information, instead its always using the default parsefilter.json file all the time. I am not able to figure out what is causing this kind a problem. Whether its a maven dependency issue or  its an issue with the default project.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code was generated from the archetype, then the parsefilter.json should be in the right place i.e. *src/main/resources/*.

When using Eclipse, make sure you import the project as a Maven project. This will add *src/main/resources/* to the classpath. Eclipse will get the dependencies and manage the classes etc... I routinely run topologies in Eclipse without any problems.

This is fine for testing and debugging but the best approach is to run the code outside Eclipse as indicated in the README. Another option, if you haven't installed Storm is to use

```
 mvn clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=insert.package.CrawlTopology -Dexec.args="-conf crawler-conf.yaml -local"
```

to run it in local mode outside of Eclipse.

Comment: I wanted to comment out that, please make more installation and usage documents. The current scenario of documentations is not so great.

Comment: One more question, I cannot seem to find out how to use-cases and difference between **indexer.md.filter** and **indexer.md.mapping** . Can you explain with use-cases??

Comment: @AbhishekKumar you are welcome to suggest improvements to the documentation if you can. Did you look at https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki and https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/Presentations?

Comment: see https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/Configuration#indexing
please ask new questions separately

Comment: Definitely, I would like to contribute towards improvement of the documentation.